# Percentage width of absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css

From [CSS 10.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property);

> Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. If the containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1. Note: For absolutely positioned elements whose containing block is based on a block container element, the percentage is calculated **with respect to the width of the padding box of that element**. This is a change from CSS1, where the percentage width was always calculated with respect to the content box of the parent element.

I find it rather odd that the percentage is calculated differently depending on whether the element is positioned absolutely or not. I'm pretty new to CSS however, so I'm guessing there's good reason for it. However is there any way to return the width calculation to be with respect to the containing block as opposed to the padding, without changing `position: absolute` in the child element? Currently I have `width:100%` in an absolutely positioned child element and this little nuance is tripping me up with layout, very similar to [this](https://jsfiddle.net/2swkkpyo/2/#&togetherjs=OGcpxbH1Tt) jsfiddle demonstration:

Comment: Perhaps setting the `box-sizing:border-box` on the parent container would do it?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/2swkkpyo/1/

Comment: @LGSon Just updated my example, it was meant to be `padding-right` and `text-align: right`. Since width is `100%` which is w.r.t the padding block, I can't pad the right side away from the containing block. `Padding-right` essentially does nothing.

Comment: @DaniP i think the question is : is there any way to return the width calculation to be with respect to the containing block as opposed to the padding, without changing position: absolute in the child element?

Comment: Do you want a right padding or a right margin?

Comment: @LGSon Right padding. But essentially I just want the region `div` to be the size of the containing block, not the padding block.

Comment: Posted an answer, comment on that if I got it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one that has both a right padding and a right margin, use the one you need.

If you want to fill the `region`'s parent width, set the right to 0 (`right: 0;`)

```css
*{
  border: 2px solid red;
}

html {
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
}

body {
  margin: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-right: 50px;
  position:relative;
  background: #666;
  color: #aaa;
}

.region{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  border: 2px dashed white;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="region">hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but just to be clear, I would need to manually change `region`'s `right` value if I were to every modify the padding in `body`, right?

Comment: @SergeantPenguin yes ... or just use an extra container : https://jsfiddle.net/2swkkpyo/5/

Comment: @SergeantPenguin, what do you want exactly? If you do not want to behave like an element with absolute position you don't set an absolute position

Comment: @SergeantPenguin No, not if the `region` always should fill its parent's width

Comment: @blonfu I'm working [through someone else's CSS](https://github.com/MichMich/MagicMirror), css/main.css uses `calc()` to make `body` take up the full screen, which isn't compatible with my version of chromium. Other suggestions recommend using `border-box:box-sizing` and changing padding appropriately, but changing the padding does nothing because of the little nuance in my OP and everything is absolutely positioned.

Comment: I think I understand your problem, my answer is similar to this one but I wonder if it is not easier set `position:relative` or `static`to `.region`

Answer (score 2):

Is not possible but you can do a little trick, remove the `width:100%` add `right:0` and `left:200px`→ the value of the padding of the parent:

```css
*{
  border: 2px solid red;
}

html {
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px dashed yellow;
}

body {
  margin: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 200px;
  position:relative;
  background: #000;
  color: #aaa;
}


.region{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:200px;
  right:0;
  border: 2px dashed white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="region">hello</div>
</body>
```